# Gradient descent (with line search) for convex functions viewed as alternation

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, machine-learning

I have fundamental confusion about gradient descent (with line search) and the reason it works.
I try to explain my view here, and please tell me where it goes wrong.

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function.

I think gradient descent (with line search) can be viewed as an alternating descent procedure as below

> $1. \,$ Initialize  $$ t=0, a_t = 1, x_t=0$$
>
> $2. \,$While not converged
>
> $\quad 2.1\,$Select steepest descent direction $$D_{t+1} = -\nabla f \approx \lim_{r\to0}\text{argmin}_{D: D\in{\mathbb{R}}^n, \|D\|^2=r} f(x_t + a_tD)$$
> $\quad 2.2 \,$ Select the best step
> size (line search) $$a_{t+1}=\text{argmin}_{a: a\in \mathbb{R}, a>0} f(x_t + aD_{t+1})$$
> $\quad 2.3 \,$ Update the current point $$x_{t+1}= x_t + a_{t+1} D_{t+1}$$
> $\quad 2.4 \,$ Proceed to the next step $$t =t+1 $$

Now I noticed that while $f$ is convex in its input, it is not jointly convex in $a$ and $D$. Then why such an alternating procedure is guaranteed to converge to a global minimum at all?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you start at a base point $P$, you minimize $f$ on a circle (or $n$-sphere, whatever) of fixed radius with center $P$ (which gives you a direction $D$) and then you minimize $f$ on a line going through $P$ in direction $D$, which gives you a circle of a new radius, and so on. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it first picks the steepest descent direction (there is an analytical solution for that: just go to the opposite direction of gradient) And then perform an exact line search to know how far in that direction you should go.  Note that  
I am not inventing something new. Just trying to describe what the standard gradient descent does.

Comment: In what way is 2.1 equivalent to computing the negative gradient? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @user25004 : This is not what the gradient descent algorithm does ; the gradient descent algorithm changes the base point, and with the description you give me (and from what I understood from it) the base point doesn't change. All you change is the direction in which you look (starting at that base point) and the distance at which you think the solution is from the basepoint, in that direction. That's why I argued.

Comment: Note that I'm not sure how your algorithm behaves in the presence of multiple minimums, such as with the function $\max \{\|x\|^2-1, 0\}$ (which is convex).

Comment: Yeah, I missed the fact that the base point isn't changing either. There's something missing here. This simply isn't the gradient method.

Comment: Okay. You are right the algorithm is messed up here. I will correct it. But all I try to highlight and ask about is the non-joint-convexity of objective wrt search direction and step size in each iteration.

Comment: By the way, dear voters! It is not a good practice to vote for closing a question that contains some confusion, Especially when the goal of asking is specified as, resolving the confusion!

Comment: @ Michael Grant: In 2.1 I was trying to formalize "the direction of maximum decrease in function". After your question, I doubt that the steepest descent direction and the direction with maximum decrease in function value are the same or not. I see that one is talking about function and the other about directional derivative. (Should try to use Taylor's theorem to see). I am not sure yet. Thanks for mentioning this.

Comment: In gradient descent, $D_{t+1}$ is $-\nabla f(x_t)$. This isn't equivalent to the formula you've given. I'm not sure it's very helpful to try to view gradient descent as an alternating minimization procedure.  There are relatively short convergence proofs for gradient descent, but I think they use different ideas.  Note that gradient descent also converges using a sufficiently small fixed step size (under certain mild assumptions).

Comment: Your corrected version is still not correct. The gradient is an *infinitesimally local* property. You cannot define it in the manner you have done in 2.1, which searches along a hypersphere around the current iterate.

Comment: I voted for closure, and I maintain that vote. The premise of this question remains fatally flawed. *This simply isn't gradient descent.* Any claims of convergence and/or performance for gradient descent in no way map to your approach here. Change the title, remove all claims that this is gradient descent, and I will remove my downvote.

Comment: 2.3 is still wrong as well... it should be $x_{t+1}=x_t+a_{t+1}D_{t+1}$.

Comment: I see! the source of confusion was that I used to think steepest direction comes from 2.1. Now I agree.

Comment: 2.1 is *still* not correct as written. You are attempting to keep $a_t$ in there, and it's just not going to work. You simply need to give up on this idea that "gradient descent can be viewed as an alternating descent procedure." It can't be.

Comment: Does $a_t$ being there or not have anything to do with the solution of optimization problem in 2.1? (What is the difference between looking for a direction which is the best, or looking for a direction which multiplied by $a_t$ is the best?) Note that the coefficient $a_t$ is fixed in that problem.

Comment: Yes, it does. You do not get $-\nabla f$ unless $a_t$ is exactly 1 on 2.1. Otherwise you get $-a_t\nabla f$, and this scaling error has consequences in 2.2 and 2.3 as well. Bottom line: $a_t$ does not belong in 2.1, and gradient descent is not an alternating descent procedure.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the confusion is that the problem is convex in terms of $x$, but not (understood to be) convex in terms of the step size $\alpha$ (given the statement about not jointly convex).

However, when we do a line search, we restrict $f$ to another convex set (the line). This, then, is also a convex problem, for which we find the minimum (to give us the step size). This must also bring us closer to the minimum of the original problem. If it does not, then the gradient is zero and we are at the minimum already.

So if this process converges, it must converge to the global minimum. I believe convergence follows from the convergence of ordinary gradient descent, simply because we are choosing the step size to be optimal.

Comment: Actually I see that $f$ is convex in terms of $D$ given a fixed $\alpha$, and $\alpha$ given a fixed $D$. However, I say it is not jointly convex in terms of the two variable together.